# Only correct answer yet bounty awarded to an incomplete answer

Tags: discussion, bounties

I recently joined stackoverflow and found  a bounty question. After working on it I came up with a very elegant solution that completely solved the problem that the person was asking.  Being new, I did not have enough to offer a bounty to others to look at my answer, nor did I even know that was possible at the time.  Here is a link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27468858/4350148 and to my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27468858/4350148.  The bounty was in fact awarded to someone who admitted that he did not work out all the details.  I tried commenting on the other answers  to spur those who gave answers look at my answer.  Even though I posted a couple of days before the end of the  bounty no one looked at or commented on it.  Then right at the end of the bounty period it was awarded to another answer, without the questioner ever looking at or commenting on my answer. I would have thought that the person asking the question would be interested in such a complete solution to his problem.

Certainly this discourages me from working on other questions. It not so much about my ego as it is about fairness and such an elegant solution not being given  it's just attention.

So what might have been useful? Perhaps one thing is to be able to review the bounty giver.   For example, in this case, the question asked was very good but the bounty reviewer did not have the skills to evaluate the correct answer. Interestingly enough neither did anyone who reviewed the answers. Most likely they simply did not look at my answer. Perhaps there is nothing that can be done and that is OK.  Being  new here perhaps I just got unlucky in this case and this is a rare event.  In any case I do think being able to state my experience is something useful for others to know.

Comment: The person placing the bounty can award it to whoever (s)he wants. After all, that person used his/her *own* rep to do it.

Comment: Whoever marked it, go ahead and delete my question

Answer (score 14):

I see nothing problematic here. A bounty was offered by a high-rep user who had an interest in the problem, and it's completely up to them which answer they choose.

You're not guaranteed a bounty, no matter how "correct" you believe your answer to be. I should point out that the answer which won the bounty was the highest-voted on that question, was extremely detailed (with diagrams, even), and was very well written.

Bounties are there to bring attention and to encourage better answers, but there's no way we can enforce that the "best" answer (if we even know what that is) must win the bounty.

Answer (score 6):

I see a lot of people put a lot of effort into answering this question.  But the person who chose the bounty winner left a very clear comment describing their reason for for not selecting it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160122/mysql-query-to-get-intersection-of-numerous-queries-with-limits/27468858#comment43402375_27413738)

> It was a hard choice to figure out who to give the bounty, but I ran out of time, a choice had to be made. This was a great contender, but invisal's method won by a hair-length due to (1) a more universally readable approach SQL-wise (enough people less experienced with user variables), which possibly can be a little more performant as well, although that highly depends on circumstances, and does require some heavy query building instead of a generic temp table + single query approach, and (2) the beginnings of an second pass / adjusting algo (although not near complete).

I'm not going to venture whether or not his selected answer is "correct", as I don't want to spend a couple hours investigating the question as well as his and your answers.  But it seems to me that he put some thought into the award, and wasn't acting out of spite or ignorance.

Like everything else, when you gamble (with your time), you win some and you lose some.  In bounties, it's a big win vs. lots of time "wasted" (although, you might get lots of rep for that answer over time, so in the end maybe it won't be).  Same goes for regular questions as well.

It's up to you to decide if helping others for fake internet rep is worth it.  Obviously, if you don't see the value in participating, then you shouldn't.

Comment: @danb Yes, he did comment.  No, I didn't say he commented  on your solution.  He isn't required to.  But way to go ignoring the point I was making.